# The most general higher-order Euler-Lagrange via exterior calculus and forms

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, field-theory, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

I can myself formulate and calculate [Euler-Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for first-order exterior calculus lagrangians, such as $L=L(A,dA; x)$ (e.g., I checked the Chern-Simons theory case, both abelian and non-abelian cases), and so

$$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial A}-d\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial dA}=0.$$

Is also this EL equation valid formally for zero forms $\phi$ such as

$$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}-d\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial d\phi}=0~?$$

What about spinor (anticommuting $c$-numbers) fields $\Psi$? Naively, one would be expect weird (-) signs from parity such as

$$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \Psi}-(-s)^pd\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial d\Psi}=0,$$

as well!

My question is simple: how can we generalize this EL equation in the case of higher $p$-form fields AND higher order derivatives, since $d^2=0$ settles a problem. In the case of an action with Hodge-star or generalized inner products, how can we proceed? Should we have an EL extra equations? I know I made a similiar question in the past, but this addition focuses on higher order and the presence of Hodge-Star, inner products of forms in the lagrangian.

Example: how could we formulate a differential form (exterior calculus like) lagrangian from $$L=\partial_{\mu\nu\sigma}F^{\mu\nu\sigma}-V(A,\partial A,\partial^2 A,\partial^3A),$$ $A=A(x)$ is the two-form from which the 3-form $F$ is derived (let me suppose $F_3=dA$ for simplicity, abelian case), even if meaningless, ill-defined, in nature or physics? I am well aware this particular lagrangian would not be acceptable but it is only an example of what I would like to be able to do. To translate the pure index notation from tensors to exterior-calculus only stuff.

Reviewed question: what is the most general Euler-Lagrange operator expression taking into account higher-order derivatives of scalar, vector, $p$-vector ($p$-forms) and their multispinorial variants? How does affect the sign before the derivatives in the Euler operator? Is that affected if we include the Hodge star operator and inner products?